# How to improve the efficiency of pandas.nlargest?

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have a DataFrame, that is:
[image]

Now I want to select two largest element of each row. So I do in this way, and profile it:
[image]

But it's too slow, and how can I improve it? What's the `fillformat` means?

Comment: IIUC you could use `np.sort` for this: `np.sort(df)[:,-2:]` should work

Comment: If you want it sorted in descending order then you can do `np.sort(df)[:,::-1][:,:2]`

Comment: My method is right to do the job, but the performance of that is too slow, so I  wanna to know how I can improve it. I think sort is quite slower than np.argparition.

Comment: have you tried timing difference between your method and mine?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`np.sort`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) to achieve what you want:

```
In [4]:
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,3))
df

Out[4]:
          0         1         2
0 -0.501631  0.729800  0.457293
1  0.259507  1.090150 -0.688817
2  0.611032  2.504964 -0.600550
3 -0.432279 -1.087437 -0.552484
4 -1.046578 -0.804681  0.477211
```

call `np.sort` and then slice the array:

```
In [37]:
np.sort(df)[:,-2:]

Out[37]:
array([[ 0.45729257,  0.7297998 ],
       [ 0.25950659,  1.09014974],
       [ 0.61103167,  2.50496433],
       [-0.55248373, -0.43227871],
       [-0.80468078,  0.47721114]])
```

If you want the values in descending order then reverse the array using slicing notation:

```
In [34]:
np.sort(df)[:,::-1][:,:2]

Out[34]:
array([[ 0.7297998 ,  0.45729257],
       [ 1.09014974,  0.25950659],
       [ 2.50496433,  0.61103167],
       [-0.43227871, -0.55248373],
       [ 0.47721114, -0.80468078]])
```